# Перебор массива с добавлением класса по определенным заранее атрибутам id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Мой вопрос о массивах и его проверке. Необходимо следующее.

На странице есть `div`-ы с атрибутом `data-id="38383"`, причем эти `id` постоянно разные.

**Что нужно**: записать в массив определенные `id`. Далее делаем проверку на наличие этих `div`-ов с атрибутами `data-id`, указанными в массиве и выполняем добавление класса этому блоку с указанным `id`.

Выглядит так:

```
<div class="pr" data-id="10230"></div>
```

Comment: Где Ваша попытка реализации кода?

Comment: да я вот как то пробую, но не пойму что делаю не так)

Comment: @Дмитрий, как определяются эти "определённые" дивы?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, в массив заносим список id, далее ищем на странице класс .pr с data-id если id в массиве с data-id совпадает, добавляем классу с тем id с которым совпало дополнительный класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Из комментария**
> *@CbIPoK2513*, в массив заносим список id, далее ищем на странице класс .pr с data-id если id в массиве с data-id совпадает, добавляем классу с тем id с которым совпало дополнительный класс

```js
let prArr = [
  '1', '2', '4', '5'
];

for(var i=0; i<prArr.length; i++) {
  let elem = $('.pr[data-id="'+prArr[i]+'"]'); // объявляем объект
  if(elem.length > 0){ // Если объект существует
    elem.addClass('asd'); // Добавляем ему класс
  }
  // P.s. 
  // Указав в цикле условие
  // if(elem.length == 1) {
  //   elem.eq(0).addClass('asd');
  // }
  // Можно избежать таких моментом, если на странице, допустим случайно, существуют больше одного одинаковых элементов.
}
```

```css
.asd {color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="pr" data-id="1">block 1</div>
<div class="pr" data-id="2">block 2</div>
<div class="pr" data-id="2">block 2</div> <!-- допустим такой вариант, что элементов с data-id="2" - две штуки. -->
<div class="pr" data-id="3">block 3</div>
<!-- Пропустим 4 -->
<div class="pr" data-id="5">block 5</div>
```

Отличия от ответа *@Vladimir*
Перебор идёт не всех элементов с классом `pr`, а конкретно тех, что указанны в массиве.
Ну и написан код на JQ, как это было указанно в метке вопроса)

Comment: супер, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Что-то такого типа?

```js
var red = ['10230', '10236'];
document.querySelectorAll('.pr').forEach(function(div) {
  if (red.includes(div.dataset.id)) {
    div.classList.add('red');
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="pr" data-id="10230">10230</div>
<div class="pr" data-id="10231">10231</div>
<div class="pr" data-id="10232">10232</div>
<div class="pr" data-id="10233">10233</div>
<div class="pr" data-id="10234">10234</div>
<div class="pr" data-id="10235">10235</div>
<div class="pr" data-id="10236">10236</div>
```